# Clustering: measure of dispersion based on distances

Tags: clustering, variance, dispersion

I am having a set of strings, they have been alligned and I have a matrix of pairwise distances. Now the objects have to be clustered yet I do not know the number of clusters beforehand. I would like to calculate some parameters that would help me decide - starting with intra-cluster variance and gap statistics.
The point is that I just have the distance matrix, not the coordinates themselves. What kind of analyses could I performed based on that?

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use the [Ward's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%27s_method) implemented in scikit-learn or [fastcluster](http://danifold.net/fastcluster.html). It will produce a dendrogram, and you scan spot at which level you should cut the dendrogram by looking at the variance decrease (sort of elbow method), cf. [this post on se](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108150/cluster-analysis-ward-how-to-evaluate-number-of-clusters-and-their-quality).